# Captcha always show the same number in my first login

Tags: javascript

I am using the below javascript to load the captcha in my site. This is working fine.But in my first login it defaultly show the number "5AbD". How can i change it.

http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1369/simple-captcha-code-in-javascript/

I user the above link javascrtipt. I can't able to post this script here..

Comment: You didn't include any code...

Comment: I can't add my javascript code here.

Comment: @user2176150 You're not allowed to add it or you're not sure how? You could link to a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) or you could paste your code (indent it by four spaces). At the moment your question says "I am using the below javascript" even though there isn't any... without it, our ability to help you is very limited.

Comment: I can not able to post my full code here it doesn't allow .

Comment: Please see up updated question.

Answer (score 1):

You dont provide many details, but often something like this is related to a random number being generated every time with the same seed.  If you rolled your own captcha I would look into how you are generating the string.  Commonly one passes the system tick count as the random number seed.

Otherwise, you don't really provide enough information for anyone to give a helpful answer.

Edit:

1) After seeing your code, first I want to say that as captcha this is extremely flawed.  The whole point is that a bot cant determine the code and automatically enter it.  This is why they are usually images generated on the server. It is difficult to extract the value from an image.

2) It is showing the same value every time because you have not coded it otherwise.  You are literally starting with the same -hard coded- value and modifying that.  Look into the Math.random() function for generating a random number for the initial value instead of hard coding that.  But, referencing point #1, I would scrap this whole javascript thing altogether because as captcha it's useless because a bot could just grab the value of that control and fill out the form with it.

3) The steps for implementing captcha are usually something like: generate the random string on the server, save that string to session, generate an image with that string (with some noise/font funkiness to prevent an image processor from easily being able to read the text), then display the image on the page.  The actual string value never leaves the server.  When the form is submitted, you just compare the user value with the value you previously stored in the session.  But rather than go through all of that (unless the whole point is as a learning exercise),  you might think about using any of the pre-made captcha controls such as recaptcha, etc.  Either way, look into the random number function, because as long as you are always starting with the same hard coded values then you will always get the same result.